# Copy file from folder to other folder by my_file.nuspec

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, nuget

I have a .nuspec file. I need copy a `DLL File` from folder to other folder, but this file do not can to be a reference this Project. Below, my xml file(.nuspec):

```
<package>
    <metadata>
        <id>SisAmilNetRelatorios.Site.Paulo</id>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <authors>Cubo Tecnologia</authors>
        <description>01.SisAmilNetRelatorios.Site (Camada de apresentação)</description>
    </metadata>
    <files>
        <file src="SisAmilNetRelatorios.Site/AjaxControlToolkit/4.1.50731.0/AjaxControlToolkit.dll" target="lib/net40" />
        <file src="SisAmilNetRelatorios.Site/Interop.Shell32/1.0.0.0/Interop.Shell32.dll" target="lib/net40" /> 
        <file src="SisAmilNetRelatorios.Site/Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms/11.0.3442.2/Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms.dll" target="lib/net40" />
        <file src="SisAmilNetRelatorios.Site/Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms/10.0.40219.1/Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms.dll" target="lib/net40" />
        <file src="NETFramework/v4.0/System.configuration.dll" target="lib/net40" />
        <file src="NETFramework/v4.0/System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll" target="lib/net40" />
        <file src="NETFramework/v4.0/System.Data.dll" target="lib/net40" />
        <file src="NETFramework/v4.0/System.dll" target="lib/net40" />
        <file src="NETFramework/v4.0/System.Drawing.dll" target="lib/net40" />
        <file src="NETFramework/v4.0/System.ServiceProcess.dll" target="lib/net40" />
        <file src="NETFramework/v4.0/System.Web.ApplicationServices.dll" target="lib/net40" />
        <file src="NETFramework/v4.0/System.Web.dll" target="lib/net40" />
        <file src="NETFramework/v4.0/System.Web.DynamicData.dll" target="lib/net40" />
        <file src="NETFramework/v4.0/System.Web.Entity.dll" target="lib/net40" />
        <file src="NETFramework/v4.0/System.Web.Extensions.dll" target="lib/net40" />
        <file src="NETFramework/v4.0/System.Web.Services.dll" target="lib/net40" />
        <file src="NETFramework/v4.0/System.EnterpriseServices.dll" target="lib/net40" />
        <file src="NETFramework/v4.0/System.EnterpriseServices.Wrapper.dll" target="lib/net40" />
    </files>    
</package
```

>

This file can not be refenced, just copied.

```
<file src="NETFramework/v4.0/System.EnterpriseServices.Wrapper.dll" target="lib/net40" />
        </files>
```

This way, it's been referenced. This reference belong to other file.

Answer (score 0):

What I want is impossible. The NuGet package do not work this way. If there are DLL's in my folder, the NuGet will install it. If someone needs, you must install in the hand.

Post closed.